# In Psalms 2:7, does the expression 'this day' forbid the thought that Jesus is eternal?

Tags: christology

> *Psalms 2:7:* 'Thou art my Son; this day have I begotten thee'

Does the expression 'this day' forbid the thought that Jesus is eternal?

Sorry for being not an expert, but that expression makes me think that the relation between Jesus and God was different before 'this day', maybe before that 'this day' Jesus was not the Son of God, and therefore Jesus is not eternal.

Peace be with you.

<sub>*And, overall, for those who like to know the denomination to which the asker belongs, I inform I'm a Christian and Adoptionist.*</sub>

Comment: Adoptionist Roman Catholic.

Answer (score 3):

The Bible suggest otherwise. In the New Testament this passage was viewed as a prophecy of the resurrection.

Acts 13:32-34 NLT

“And now we are here to bring you this Good News. The promise was made to our ancestors, and God has now fulfilled it for us, their descendants, by raising Jesus. This is what the second psalm says about Jesus: ‘You are my Son. Today I have become your Father. ’ For God had promised to raise him from the dead, not leaving him to rot in the grave. He said, ‘I will give you the sacred blessings I promised to David.’